# Google App Engine Unable to Send GCM Token

Tags: android

I am working with Google App Engine .I want to Send GCM toke(RegID) to App Engine Server.But Problem is that when i pass RegId as a parameter Nothing happen and when i pass normal string like"abcefghi" the string is passed to server
 my code is shown below

```
public class SendInstanceidAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, UpdateInstanceIdResult> {
    private UpdateinstanceidAPI updateinstanceidAPIservice;
    private String token;
    private String scholarNumber;
    private String schoolId;
    private RegistrationIntentService registrationIntentService;

    public SendInstanceidAsync(RegistrationIntentService registrationIntentService, String token, String schoolId, String scholarNumber) {
        this.token = token;
        this.scholarNumber = scholarNumber;
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
        this.registrationIntentService = registrationIntentService;
    }

    @Override
    protected UpdateInstanceIdResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        UpdateInstanceIdResult updateInstanceIdResult = new UpdateInstanceIdResult();

        if (updateinstanceidAPIservice == null) {
            UpdateinstanceidAPI.Builder builder = new UpdateinstanceidAPI.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)

                    .setRootUrl("http://xxx.xxx.x.x:xxxx/_xx/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new UpdateinstanceidAPIRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initializeUpdateinstanceidAPIRequest(UpdateinstanceidAPIRequest<?> request) throws IOException {
                            request.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
            updateinstanceidAPIservice = builder.build();

        }

        try {
            updateInstanceIdResult = updateinstanceidAPIservice.updateInstanceID(schoolId, scholarNumber, token).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return updateInstanceIdResult;
    }
```